# Boolean Algebra, Simplification: Sum of products

Tags: boolean-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boolean Algebra, Simplification: Don't know the method used](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7126/boolean-algebra-simplification-dont-know-the-method-used)

Based on a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7126/boolean-algebra-simplification-dont-know-the-method-used), the answer I got for the "sum of products" method was:

```
RC' + RCG' + RCGM'
```

Just for completeness, can someone help walk me through to how this was arrived at?  Thanks again in advance!

Comment: Hi Hamster. I will answer in the original thread. This thread will probably get closed.

Comment: That's okay.  I'll stick with the previous, then.